# "Please, contact with Mr. Jonson" or 'Please, contact Mr. Jonson"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

What's the difference between contact WITH a certain person Vs. contact a certain person? I am not sure about the preposition.

For example, one has sent me a message and I want him to talk about that with my colleague. What's the correct way to tell him that out of the following choices?

> "Please, contact with Mr. Jonson"

or

> "Please, contact Mr. Jonson"?

N.b. In the [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contact) it isn't clear to me what's the correct one in this context (see 2a and b):

> 1: to bring into contact 2a: to enter or be in contact with : JOIN The
> spark contacted the gunpowder. b: to get in communication with Contact
> your local dealer.

Comment: Please edit to show that you have looked up the transitive verb *contact* [in a dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contact), what you found, and what questions remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please contact Mr. Johnson [about or regarding this matter]. [no preposition, direct object].
- Your contact with Mr. Johnson has been sporadic.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: *Please contact Mr. Jonson*

"Contact" (as in the question) is a transitive verb. You *contact someone*. The someone is the object. Do not use "contact with".

However, "contact" can also be used as a noun. In a similar sentence, the noun does require a helper verb and preposition: "Please make contact with Mr. Johnson."